# Check connectivity on virtual machine in vCenter

Tags: powershell, powercli, vcenter

I am trying to write a small powershell script that checks the health of a newly started server. Here's what I want to do:

1. Start VM if it's not already started
2. Wait for Guest Tools to start running
3. Run the powershell script `Test-Connection MyDCServer -Quiet` using `Invoke-VMScript`
4. Act on whether the check return $true or not.

I have 1. and 2. donem but I am running into trouble on 3. All I get back from `Invoke-VMScript` is a *string presenting the output* from the script, when I really want the *return value* from the script that I invoked.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
$result = Invoke-VMScript ...
$result.ScriptOutput
$result.ExitCode
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This is exactly the answer to my question, namely how to get the return value from the script.